# Как сделать с помощью htaccess редирект категории и вложенных страниц?

Tags: .htaccess

Как сделать с помощью htaccess редирект категории и вложенных страниц.
То есть было раньше так http://akaricar.ru/completedorder/toyota-corolla
Стало вот так http://akaricar.ru/completedorder/good_cars/toyota-corolla

Как сделать редирект со старых страниц на новые, с добавлением рубрики?

Comment: Интересно, а как правила в .htaccess должны угадывать к какой рубрике относится та или иная машина?

Comment: Не понял вас. У меня просто была стопка машин в одной странице я ее перенес в другую рубрику

Comment: У вас там две рубрики и в обеих есть машины.

Comment: Да плохие и хорошие. Плохие недавно добавлены. В хороших сбились ссылки

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, нужен был 301 редирект для переадресации старых страниц на новые, а не внутренний редирект для запуска файла отличного от адреса обращения.

Comment: @Visman, я уже понял, поэтому и удалил ответ

Comment: Не совсем понял то есть мне в ручную все делать?

Comment: Я как бы уже начал делать только вот многовато.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, исправьте свой ответ и все.

Comment: @DevilScream, изменил ответ на 301й, попробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^completedorder/([^/]*)$  /completedorder/good_cars/$1 [R=301,L]
```

вот так вот должен отрабатывать 301й редирект

Comment: Сейчас проверю.

Comment: Чет вообще ничего не поменялось

Comment: я понял)в обратном порядке...сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: Не все равно  не робит чет.

Comment: круто. Работает. Я вас наверно уже подзапарил. Но теперь другие страницы которые там были не работают.

Comment: Там как бы есть плохие и хорошие машины, по старым ссылкам которые сбились все хорошо но вот страницы типа  http://akaricar.ru/completedorder/bad_cars не работают. У меня косяк только с новыми машинами был. На данный момент редирект убрал.

Comment: по этому правилу совершено любые страницы по урл completedorder/чтолибо  - перенаправит на /completedorder/good_cars/что-либо, усли вас много страниц то лучше сделать конкретные 301е редиректы для конкретных страниц

Comment: То есть типо так ? Redirect 301 /completedorder/mitsubishi-outlander-2 http://akaricar.ru/completedorder/good_cars/mitsubishi-outlander-2

Comment: /completedorder/mitsubishi-outlander-2$  /completedorder/good_cars/mitsubishi-outlander-2  [R=301,L]

Comment: А в чем разница между моим и вашем вариантом?